# Can't get sbt-web to work with npm for frontend dependencies

Tags: playframework-2.3, sbt-web

I'm trying to use sbt-web and [sbt-js-engine](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-js-engine/) in particular to resolve my dependencies with npm instead of webjars.

My problem is that the dependencies are not copied in the `target/web/public/main/lib` folder during the `web-stage` task as it is the case using webjar.

I used the [sample project from sbt-js-engine](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-js-engine/tree/1.0.2/sbt-js-engine-tester) to make my tests. With this project, I expect to find the `console-browserify` dependency from the `package.json` file in the `target/web/public/main/lib` folder, but it is not.

[image]

Maybe I'm completely misunderstanding something ?

Comment: Hi, sorry, I can't help you because I wasn't even able to get to the stage you are in. How did you manage to make get the `node_modules` folder appear? I had to manually run `sbt web-assets:jseNpmNodeModules` to fetch the npm dependencies.

Comment: I also had to run `sbt web-assets:jseNpmNodeModules` manually.

Comment: Hi, it seems to be an [issue](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/3565) with playframework. Maybe try to upgrade to Play 2.4.2 and see if it is solved

Comment: @JulienBoulay thanks mate! I'll take a look :-)

Answer (score 4):

I've had a similar problem myself when trying to pulling some test dependencies with npm. after a few hour searching for a solution I ended up just writing a task in my build.sbt to move the directories manually: (May not be the best solution but a work around)

```
lazy val copy_node_modules = taskKey[Unit]("Copys the node_module to the test target dir")

copy_node_modules := {
  val node_modules = new File("node_modules")
  val target = new File("target/web/public/main/public/lib/")
  IO.copyDirectory(node_modules,target,true, true)
}

addCommandAlias("get_npm_deps", ";web-assets:jseNpmNodeModules;copy_node_modules")
```

then you can use "get_npm_deps" to pull in the npm based dependencies